# Placeholder not showing with Aria

Tags: html, vue.js, wai-aria

I have a placeholder where you can search several names. I made it so the screen reader NVDA says the number of people that is in the list for every toggle you press (for example, if you press a, it says there is 20 results, if you press ag, there is 12, etc..)

The problem is that when you finish deleting all the letters, the screen reader reads all the total of the people in the searcher, and i don't want that, insthead of that i want it to not say nothing.
Here is my code (the important part is this one)

```html
<div class="sr-only" alt="This div read on screen reader the results of searched persons and its not visible" aria-atomic="true" aria-live="assertive">
    <span class="sr-only" v-bind:aria-label=" 'Showing '+filterPeople.length + ' results.'"></span>
</div>
```

and this other one

```html
<div class="nav-new-scrollbar"></div>

<div v-show="addMore == 2 && myPeople.length < 5 && !plannerOpened" class="wc-search"> 
    <img src="imagesnew/search-icon-peopleSearch.svg" title="Search" alt="Search" tabindex="0" class="wc-searchbox-btn" />
    <input v-model="search" type="text" placeholder="Search to add a person" tabindex="0" class="keyboard-outline" aria-label="Search to add a peopleF" />
    
    <div v-show="search != ''" class="wc-select-city">
        <div v-for="(person, index) in filterPeople" :key="person.Id + '-' + index" class="wc-result-people" tabindex="0" :value="city.Id" @click.stop.prevent="addCity(person.Id)" @keyup.enter.stop.prevent="addPerson(person.Id)">
            <p :title="person.PersonName">
                {{ city.PersonName }}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not quite enough code to really see what the problem is but I can point out a few things that need to be fixed that are **not** causing your problem but are general accessibility best practices.

- You have an `alt` on a `<div>` which is not valid html.  If you run it through an html validator such as https://validator.w3.org/nu/ you'll get an error regarding `alt`.
- Unless the announcement you want the screen reader to say is super critical, avoid using `aria-live="assertive"`.  Use `aria-live="polite"` instead.
- It looks like you have an `aria-label` on a `<span>` but you don't have a `role` on your `<span>`.  `aria-label` is general ignored on non-semantic elements.  See the third last bullet point on https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support
- It looks like you are updating the `aria-label` on the `<span>` based on your search results and are not taking advantage of `aria-live` on the container.  `aria-live` will announce any text changes made *inside* of elements.  So if you inserted new text between the `<span>new text here</span>`, it would announce "new text here".

Given all that, I *think* your code should work if you had something like:

```
<div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
  <span> <!-- put text here --> </span>
</div>
```

So when you type 'a', you'd have

```
<div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
  <span> Showing 20 results </span>
</div>
```

and the screen reader would say *"Showing 20 results"*.  And when you delete all the characters, you'd put nothing (or blanks) in the span.

```
<div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
  <span> </span>
</div>
```

and the screen reader *should* be silent (because there's no new text to read, or rather, the new text is just blank).